# Confused about higher-order-function in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I trying to understand functional programming in javascript. But I am confused about higher-order-function. I need a more detailed explanation.

Here is the program I wrote

```
var outer = function() {
    return function(name) {
        return "My name is " + name;
    }
}

var a = outer();
var b = a('khoyer');
b;
```

Why I can't write instead like this

```
var outer = function() {
    return function(name) {
        return "My name is " + name;
    }
}
var a = outer("khoyer");
a;
```

It shows no output. but why?

I'm asking this for clarification about the concept. why and why not. and further, please suggest some good book written about core concept about functional programming or any types of article / video tutorial.

thank you!

Comment: yes. it was typing error!. edited. but isn't my main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you think because the function `outer` takes no parameters, but returns an anonymous function with one parameter `name`. If you use your second example:

```
var a = outer("khoyer");
```

Then the string `"khoyer"` will be assigned to an array called `args`. This array will contain the string, but the string won't be passed to the inner function because the function takes a parameter, and it's not reading the arguments because your code doesn't tell it to.

In short, you need to create a variable that holds a higher-order function before you can call it, because of the differences between `arguments` and `parameters`.

For more information:

https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html